# Rails delete player not deleting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

A confirm message comes up asking if you are sure to delete but then the player stays there.

Here is my destroy method in the controller

```
  def destroy
    Player.find(params[:id]).destroy
    redirect_to :action => 'index'
   end
```

Here is my delete link

```
<ul>
<% @players.each do |p| %>
<li>
    <%= link_to p.name, {:action => 'show', :id => p.id} -%> email:<%= p.email %> 
    <%= link_to 'edit', {:action => "edit",
        :id => p.id} %> 
    <%= link_to "Delete", {:action => 'destroy' ,:id => p.id}, :confirm => "Are you sure you want to delete this item?" %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
<p><%= link_to "Add new player", {:action => 'new' }%></p>
```

Here is the log

```
Started GET "/players" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-25 15:30:55 +0200
Processing by PlayersController#index as HTML
  Player Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "players".* FROM "players" 
  Rendered players/index.html.erb within layouts/application (1.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 46ms (Views: 45.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)
[2013-03-25 15:30:55] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true
```

Comment: try this <%= link_to "Delete", {:action => 'destroy', :method => 'delete', :id => c.id}, :confirm => "Are you sure you want to delete this item?" %>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should specifiy the `method: 'delete'` since links by default are `method: 'get'`.

rails router will see that `delete` and act accordinly

Comment: What should I put in my delete method?

Comment: no, you misunderstood.. do something like `<%= link_to "Delete", {:action => 'destroy', :method => 'delete' ,:id => c.id},
        :confirm => "Are you sure you want to delete this item?" %>`

Comment: this is will make link_to do a HTTP DELETE request which the rails router will recognize and route to the proper action in the controller. Without this it will do a HTTP GET request, which most likely route to the :show action

Comment: also, you shouldn't put anything special in the destroy action, unless you want to do anything special while destroying the model (like emailing or something like that)

Comment: ok i've removed the contents of destroy and used your link and its still not deleting.

Comment: can you show the output from logs once you click on the link?

Answer (score 0):

Your player is called `detroy`.
Don't you get a syntax error? Aren't your in developement mode?

```
def destroy
  Player.find(params[:id]).destroy
  redirect_to :action => 'index'
end
```

Correct your method.

Comment: No I was not getting a syntax error that is probably why I didnt pick it up

Answer (score 0):

Its good to format the link_to for the delete button as follows.

```
<%= link_to "Delete", path_for_delete_action(c), :method => :delete,
    :confirm => "Are you sure you want to delete this item?" %>
```

or just specify the **controller** and **method** in your current implementation.

Answer (score 0):

2 issues:

- You misspelled `destroy` in your controller.
- You need to add `method: :delete` to the `link_to`

Answer (score 0):

Specify the HTTP method, You don't need to define the delete method.

It's an HTTP DELETE method NOT a ruby method.

```
<%= link_to "Delete", {:action => 'destroy', :id => c.id, :method => :delete}, 
        :confirm => "Are you sure you want to delete this item?" %>
```

I don't use that particular syntax, so if that doesn't work, try this one:

```
<%= link_to "Delete", player_url(c), :method => :delete,
        :confirm => "Are you sure you want to delete this item?" %>
```